# R: How to check the first instance certain individual values show up in a matrix table?

Tags: r

I need to find out the first time customers ordered certain fruits [please see fruitlist table as my lookup table]. I want to find out who these customers are and what OrderID they first ordered these fruits.

[image: Lookup table]

This is how my Order table looks like, which is my main table.

[image: Main Table]

And this is what I am hoping the result would look like:

[image]

Sorry about the pasted pictures. Still learning stackoverflow formatting.

If there's a better way of rephrasing the question, please let me know.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A potential `tidyverse` solution:

First, use `pivot_longer` gather fruits in single column. Then, `filter` to include only those in your look-up table (`fruitlist`).

To get the first order for a customer, first `group_by` the `customer_name` and `fruit`), and select first fruit with `slice`.

Note this assumes your dates are in order from oldest to most recent. If your dates are not you can sort/order before `slice` with `arrange(orderdate)`.

```
library(tidyverse)

order_df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("fruit_"), names_to = "fruit_col", values_to = "fruit") %>%
  filter(fruit %in% fruitlist) %>%
  group_by(customer_name, fruit) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  arrange(orderid)
```

**Data**

```
order_df <- data.frame(
  customer_name = c("joe", "angel", "kim", "mary", "joe", "mary", "angel", "kim"),
  orderid = c(1:8),
  orderdate = c("3/6/2018", "3/3/2018", "4/15/2018", "5/11/2018", "6/23/2018", "11/18/2018", "12/1/2018", "12/20/2018"),
  fruit_col1 = c("guava", "grapefruit", "pear", "banana", "apple", "papaya", "orange", "apple"),
  fruit_col2 = c("apple", "lemon", "lemon", "orange", "grape", "apple", "apple", "lemon"),
  fruit_col3 = c("strawberry", "pear", "pear", "grapefruit", "orange", "banana", "strawberry", "banana")
)

fruitlist <- c("apple", "orange", "banana")
```